# Миксин для картинок pug

Tags: pug, mixins

На страницу добавляется картинка

```
+image('illustration.svg')
```

Я нашла миксин, но у картинок разное расширение
`

```
mixin image(name)
     img.src(src=require(`../src/images/${name}.png`) alt=name)
```

`

Как этот миксин переделать, чтобы он принимал картинки с разным расширением?
Пробовала условия, но не работает

```
mixin image(name, extensions)
if extensions == 'svg'
    img.src(src=require(`../src/images/${name}.svg`) alt=name)
else if extensions == 'png'
    img.src(src=require(`../src/images/${name}.png`) alt=name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я разобралась

Вставляю картинки

```
+image('illustration', 'svg')
+image('favicon-32x32', 'png')
```

Затем, я использую этот миксин

```
mixin image(name, ext)
if ext === 'svg'
    img.src(src=require(`../src/images/${name}.${ext}`) alt=name)
else if ext === 'png'
    img.src(src=require(`../src/images/${name}.${ext}`) alt=name)
```

Comment: А зачем условия if else? передавайте расширение напрямую в 1 строчку 
`mixin image(name, ext)
  img.src(src=require(`../src/images/${name}.${ext}`) alt=name)
 `

Comment: @Алексей, да, ты прав! Спасибо!